# How to save multiple csv files using to_csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Need to create multiple CSV files at the location

```
csv_data="D:\Desktop\DS\DSDA\Assignment\"
for a in range(60):
   csv_data = csv_data + str(a)
   csv_data = DataFrameDict[a].to_csv(csv_data.csv, index = False, header=True)`
   csv_data = ""
```

I have tried:

`file.with_suffix('.csv'), index = False)` also didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is able to create 60 CSV files using one dataframe:

```
csv_data="D:\Desktop\DS\DSDA\Assignment\"
for a in range(60):
   csv_data = csv_data + str(a)
   csv_data = DataFrameDict[a].to_csv(csv_data+str(".csv"), index = False, header=True)
   csv_data = ""
```

Comment: I think I may have dropped the ball when [I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25771401) your answer here. Was this you posting an answer to your question, or was it clarifying your question?

Answer (score 0):

First/better path for me would be to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html); however, let's stick to ur question. I would suggest adding the csv to the string addition:

```
  csv_data="D:\Desktop\DS\DSDA\Assignment\"
 for a in range(60):
     #add the '.csv' here
     csv_data = csv_data + str(a)+'.csv'
csv_data = DataFrameDict[a].to_csv(csv_data, index = False, header=True)`
#what is this line for?
csv_data = ""
```

let's see if it works